# Why is my loop not exiting when I expect?

Tags: c, arrays

I'm currently working on some practice C programming questions and I've run into one that I don't quite understand how to complete. It goes as follows:

```
Write a C program that will prompt the user to enter data about student
marks. After all the marks are entered, your program must print a short 
report showing the minimum and maximum marks (along with the ID of the students 
receiving those marks) and the average mark. The data will include student 
numbers (integers) and marks (floating point). Here's an example of what an 
interaction with your program might look like. The program's output is in 
boldface and the user's input is not.

--------------------------

student number (0 to stop): 1234
mark: 72.5
student number (0 to stop): 2345
mark: 63.47
student number (0 to stop): 67298764
mark: 86
student number (0 to stop): 0

Lowest mark: 63.47 (student 2345)
Highest mark: 86 (student 67298764)
Average mark: 73.99
```

This is what I've come up with so far:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
int marks[5];
int i;

for(i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    printf("student number (0 to stop): ");
    scanf("%d\n", marks + i);
    if (marks[i] == 0) {
        break;
    }



}

printf("\nEntered values:\n");
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    printf("%d\n",*marks);
}

return 0;
```

}
I'm just trying to get the program to follow the requirement of exiting the loop after the user inputs a `0` which is not working. I'm trying to go step by step and it seems I'm failing on the very first... Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: `if (marks[i] = 0)` --> `if (marks[i] == 0)`

Comment: Enable compiler warnings and pay heed to them! A halfway modern compiler should warn about an assignment in a condition.

Answer (score 2):

You are using a single equals `=` which is an assignment operator not `==` the comparison operator.

Answer (score 1):

You wrong. Please remove "\n" in scanf function:

```
scanf("%d", marks + i);
```

To print all member, you must change the index of array:

```
printf("%d\n",marks[i]);
```